# UITextView insertText call shouldChangeTextInRange: replacementText:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a `UITextView`. I have the delegate for `myTextView` set to `self` and, when I do normal editing, this method calls just fine:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSLog(@"Called");
}
```

In my app, I call in my code: `[myTextView insertText:@"Hello World"];`. When I do, I need to call `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` after the text is inserted. How do I do this?

Comment: You would naturally call it explicitly before making the edit and then make the edit if it returned `YES`.

Comment: @Wain - How would I call it explicitly?

Answer (score 5):

Call it explicitly. Call it before editing and only perform the edit if it returns `YES`. To call it explicitly you need to know the selected range (get the selected range with `selectedTextRange`), that's it. You already have the text to add and the text view.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answer, @Wain!

Here's what worked:

```
- (void)insertText
{
    NSString *stringToAdd = @"Hello World";

    NSString *replacementText = [myTextView.text stringByAppendingString:stringToAdd];

    [napkinTextView insertText:stringToAdd];

    [self textView:myTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:NSMakeRange(0, stringToAdd.length) replacementText:replacementText];
}
```